# Laravel SSHing to own machine

Tags: php, ssh, laravel-5

I've tried to SSH into a domain, and I could do that using laravel SSH. Now I'm trying to SSH into my own machine using laravel SSH.

Here is what I'm trying to do,

```
 $ip_address = 'ip adress';
 $port = ''; // 
 $ftp_username = 'swdf';
 $ftp_password = 'sdfsc';
 Config::set('remote.connections.production.host', $ip_address);
 Config::set('remote.connections.production.port', $port);     
 Config::set('remote.connections.production.username', $ftp_username);
 Config::set('remote.connections.production.password', $ftp_password);

        SSH::run([
            'cd Projects/test
             touch test.txt',], function ($line) {
                $decoded_txt = base64_decode($line);
            });
        return 2;
```

I've put 22 as port, 8000 as port and even removed config setting for port. These three options didn't work. Any one have idea why its working for domains and not for my machine. I've someone else machine too. It didn't work either. The machine was active all the time.

The error it is throwing is,

```
Cannot connect to ip:22. Error 110. Connection timed out
```

Comment: what ip do you use ? `127.0.0.1` ? or do you use a hostname ? `localhost` ?

Comment: I've got the solution. my remote server is in US, and I was accessing my private ip using that which is impossible.